# Is there a way to access a value computed using props in componentDidMount?

Tags: reactjs, gsap

I'm working on converting a vanilla js gsap(GreenSock) animation to react, and want to access values based on props in `componentDidMount`(where gsap tweens are called). The animation is based on https://codepen.io/zadvorsky/pen/dILAG, using Delaunay triangulation and tweens to explode a shattered image. How do I access said values?

Originally I had the calculations contained in `if(shatter)` inside `render` but the values of `rx`, `ry`, and `delay` were undefined in the tween used in `componentDidMount`. I moved said calculations to `componentDidMount` so said values would be available, but the props are not available then, even with the use of a `constructor`.

```
export class Explosion extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        shatter: false
    }
}

tl0 = new TimelineMax();
tl1 = new TimelineMax();


fragmentNode = React.createRef()
containerNode = React.createRef()

componentDidMount() {

    if (this.state.shatter) {
        const triangulatedValues = triangulate({
            this.props.width,
            this.props.height,
            this.props.startX,
            this.props.startY
        })

        const {
            vertices,
            indices
        } = triangulatedValues

        const ExplosionFragments = []

        for (let i = 0; i < indices.length; i += 3) {

            let point0 = vertices[indices[i + 0]]
            let point1 = vertices[indices[i + 1]]
            let point2 = vertices[indices[i + 2]]

            let fragmentCentroid = computeCentroid({
                point0,
                point1,
                point2
            })

            let dx = fragmentCentroid[0] - startX
            let dy = fragmentCentroid[1] - startY
            let d = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
            let rx = -30 * sign(dy)
            let ry = -90 * -sign(dx)
            let delay = d * 0.003 * randomRange(0.7, 1.1)


            let box = computeBoundingBox({
                point0,
                point1,
                point2
            })

        }
    }

    this.tl1
        .to(this.fragmentNode, 1, {
            z:500,
            rotationX:rx,
            rotationY:ry,
            ease:Power2.easeInOut
        })
        .to(this.fragmentNode, 0.4,{alpha:0}, 1)
    this.tl0
        .insert(this.tl1, delay)
}

render() {

    const {
        shatter
    } = this.state



    return (
        <Container
            ref={this.containerNode}
            onClick={this.handleToggleShatter}
        >
            {shatter ? (
                <div>
                    <OverlayImage
                    src="http://i67.tinypic.com/2eq9utk.jpg"
                    />
                    <canvas
                    width={width}
                    height={height}
                    ref={this.fragmentRef}>
                    </canvas>
                </div>
            ) : (
                <OverlayImage
                    src="http://i67.tinypic.com/2eq9utk.jpg"
                />
            )}
        </Container>
    )
}
}

export default Explosion
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/ll139x3nx7

I expect the props to be available in `componentDidMount`, but the error "Parsing error: this is a reserved word" gets thrown. This is just an error for a possible solution, and I'm open to any way forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
const triangulatedValues = triangulate({
    this.props.width,
    this.props.height,
    this.props.startX,
    this.props.startY
})
```

You're passing in an Object where the keys are `this.props.width` etc and the values are also `this.props.width` because you haven't specified any other key, so it'll try to call the key the name of the variable.

Try:

```
const triangulatedValues = triangulate({
    width: this.props.width,
    height: this.props.height,
    startX: this.props.startX,
    startY: this.props.startY
})
```